# Antlr4, How to report specific syntax error

Tags: parsing, syntax, antlr, semantics, antlr4

I am trying to use antlr4 to write some error checking for my simple grammar.

The grammar itself is constructed by functions.

ie

```
FUNCTION hello (n){
    ......
}
FUNCTION main (n) {
    ......
}
```

I am not sure how it suppose to catch specific errors such as **missing function name**, or **missing main function**

Here is what my ErrorListener looks like

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

public class SimpleErrorListener extends BaseErrorListener {
    @Override
    public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer,
            Object offendingSymbol,
            int line,
            int charPositionInLine,
            String msg,
            RecognitionException e) {
        List<String> stack = ((Parser) recognizer.getRuleInvocationStack();
        Collections.reverse(stack);
        System.err.println("rule stack: " + stack);
        System.err.println("line" + line + ":" + 
            charPositionInLine + "at" + offendingSymbol + ": " + msg);
    }
}
```

I also removed the console error listener and add this one, but I don't know how to deal with those specific errors.
Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reporting semantic errors is much easier in general than reporting syntax errors. If you want custom reporting of syntax errors, you need to alter your grammar so those syntax errors become semantic errors. For example, if you currently parse your function like this:

```
function : FUNCTION ID '(' ...
```

Then you can turn "Missing function name" into a syntax error by using one of the following rules instead:

```
function : FUNCTION ID? '(' ...

// alternate
function : FUNCTION (ID | /*missing function name; reported in listener*/) '(' ...
```

Note that your grammar will quickly become unmanageable as you add more and more special cases.

Comment: Hi, @280Z28, Thanks a lot! I've tried to edited as ID? in my grammar but it doesn't report.    function : "FUNCTION" ID? arguments variables block;

Comment: Then I also tried to see what msg it generates to ErrorListener, and I added if (msg.contains("expecting ID")) System.out.println("Error: function name undefined"); --> it did report, though I am not sure if it is the correct approach :)

Comment: For the missing main function & duplicate function name error, I added some predicates in the grammar, such as adding all function name to local HashSet and if there are duplicates, it reports error. However, using predicates may cause more than one error messages: if I had 10 functions and none of them are main function, by using this approach, it prints 10 error messages, so that I don't think it is correct the approach. :(

Comment: Thanks again for the hint @280Z28, I think I have achieved it by using predicates inside the grammar. I construct a HashMap of function ids and count the number of ids. At the end of program, I will check the number and whether the HashMap contains the key "main". :)