# Forcing a syntax error in Antlr4

Tags: java, antlr4

I have searched for hours trying to figure out how to manually create a syntax error in an Antlr4 listener.  Is it possible?

I have created a grammar that works fine, part of it looks like:

```
variableExp returns [ BigDecimal value ]
  : VARIABLE_PREFIX n = VARIABLE_NAME 
  ;
```

where VARIABLE_PREFIX is a character like "$".

I am using a listener and on exitVariableExp(), I set the value based on information outside the parser (and it's user entered so I can't put it in the parser):

```
  @Override 
  public void exitVariableExp(ExpressionsParser.VariableExpContext ctx) 
  { 
    System.out.println("In exitVariableExp()");
    ctx.value = lookupVariable(ctx.getText());
  }
```

The issue I have is that the user can type just about anything (e.g. $jfjhfjfj) that isn't a variable and this will be accepted by the parser.  I want to create a syntax error in this listener member, because I have an error listener that stores the syntax error location to show the user:

```
@Override
public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object   offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException e) throws ParseCancellationException 
  {
    System.out.println("Got syntax error.");
    errorLine = line;
    errorColumn = charPositionInLine;
    errorMessage = msg;
  }
```

but I can't figure out how to do it.  Maybe this is the wrong way to go about it?

Comment: If a variable has to start with a `$`, can't you use something that, you know, doesn't?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not a syntax error. Syntax is defined by your grammar. So as long as the code abides by the grammar, there are no syntax errors. This is probably what's putting you off in your search, because in fact you want to implement a runtime or a domain error, depending on what you're building.

Comment: I agree it's not a syntax error to the parser, but in a general sense it is to the user.  Does this mean that you can't generate a syntax error from a listener?

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm not sure what you're asking.  I'm parsing user entered input and it will have errors (bad variable names) and I want to capture that -- preferably with the error handling mechanism I already have.

Comment: Why is `$jfjhfjfj` not a variable name?  The alphabetic part is not a word in English, but then many variable names are not words.  What makes this an error?

Comment: @JimGarrison because this parser is part of a simulation and variables reference other parts that are user created.  It either exists or it doesn't.  So unless they named something jhjhfjfj, it won't exist.  The bottom line is that they may type it in wrong.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/18941263/18157

Comment: Thanks @JimGarrison, I've seen that, but no, it doesn't help.  I already  have the syntax error routine in my ErrorListener.  The problem is how to trigger a syntax error in this case so that my syntaxError function gets called and the parsing stops.

Comment: @GerardvanHelden: So an invalid token is not considered a syntax error?

Comment: @ScottHunter -- I won't speak for Gerard, but it is a valid token.  VARIABLE_NAME is any character in [a-zA-Z0-9_]. The problem is that what is references may not exist and in that case, I want to force a syntax error.

Comment: @user3125979: Then GerardvanHelden is right: an unresolved reference is NOT a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When executing a tree-walker, the parser has already run to completion, so the parser's syntax error reporting mechanism is unavailable.

Better, just rely on the parse-tree node, since it will contain all of the information necessary to report the error.

```
private static final String msg = "Syntax error: '%s' is not a valid var (at %s:%s).";

@Override 
public void exitVariableExp(VariableExpContext ctx) { 
    String value = lookupVariable(ctx.getText());
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
        Token tok = ctx.VARIABLE_NAME.getSymbol();
        int line = tok.getLine();              // 1..n
        int col = tok.getCharPositionInLine(); // 0..n
        System.out.println(String.format(msg, tok.getText(), line, col));            
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. How do you stop the tree walking?  I tried a parse cancel exception to no avail.

Comment: Again, parser has run so a parse cancel will not work. Just wrap the `ParseTreeWalker#walk` call in a `try..catch` and throw an `Exception` where you want to stop. Better to not stop, though, and report all errors at the same time.

Comment: Interesting, I'm not calling ParseTreeWalker#walk.  I do get about six lookups and therefore exceptions for a single error (e.g. parsing "@jfjfjfjfj").    That's why I wanted to stop the walking.  I would assume it is being called by the parser...

Comment: It's also interesting (frustrating) that trying to parse two characters ($h), my listener method exitVariableExp() gets called six times.  Why would it be called six times for two tokens?  I'm raising a RuntimeException each time.

Comment: I'll have to develop and example, right now it's many, many thousands of lines.

Comment: Code posted -- see above.

Comment: Using the parse listener interface is not what  you want. Your listener code is going to be executed any time the parser happens to 'try' the rule -- likely to result in inappropriate use or the masking of deeper errors. The real problem is that you are trying to convert a semantic problem into a syntactic problem. Handle syntax in the parser; semantics in a walker.

Answer (score 0):

Try what the parser is doing when it encounters a syntax error: it throws a `RecognitionException`. You can do that in your listener and exception handling will take care and report the error (and try to recover). If you don't like the recover mechanism and want to stop parsing altogether some more work is required. In this case you should throw a different exception than `RecognitionException` (because that's catched in all parser functions). The `BailErrorStrategy` uses this approach to stop parsing as soon as possible (which is good for quick syntax checks). Look there how to override some standard behavior.

Comment: I tried to do that, but I couldn't figure out what to pass the exception for the first parameter (Recognizer<?,?>).  I am using BallErrorStrategy.

Comment: Just pass in your parser instance.